# Why battery "sags" on my device and how to fix/workaround it?

Tags: battery, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

Sometimes my device shows "No SIM card" status and "0%" battery and soon powers off (even if I manage to quicky connect it to USB). After powering back on it works more or less as expected.

[image: Battery history]

Why does this happen? How to fix the issue or how to force Android to continue if battery suddenly drops to 0% (as opposed of gradually become discharged)?

Comment: Have you tried changing batteries - just to isolate the cause?

Comment: No, and it's probably tricky to get a smartphone battery. This is my sole smartphone I'm using for more than 2 years and the issue is not new.